# Is there a way to "refresh" a Springframework Repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an entity of a view, as well as an entity of one of the tables the view is joining:

```
ViewEntity
TableEntity
```

which share a primary key "SharedId".

In my service class, I declare the repositories for both entities and have a function that updates the status of the TableEntity, and returns the subsequent result of the corresponding ViewEntity with the same SharedId (which should show the updated status, as the view it is based on joining the "status" column from the TableEntity table):

```
class MyService {
    @Autowired
    ViewEntityRepository viewEntityRepository;

    @Autowired
    TableEntityRepository tableEntityRepository;

    ViewEntity updateTableEntity(String newStatus, TableEntity tableEntity) {
        tableEntity.status = newStatus;
        tableEntityRepository.save(viewEntity);
        ViewEntity ret = viewEntityRepository.findBySharedId(tableEntity.SharedId);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

The problem is the ViewEntity ret is not reflecting new status change (it has the old value of status, or null if there was no previous TableEntity corresponding to this SharedId).  Does anyone know why?

I'm guessing this is because viewEntityRepository is instantiated before the TableEntity status is saved, as subsequent calls will return a ViewEntity with the status of the TableEntity of the previous call (e.g. first call with TableEntity status = "NEW" will return a ViewEntity status = null, and second call with TableEntity status = "MOVED" will return a ViewEntity status = "NEW").

Is there a way to "refresh" or reinstantiate the viewEntityRepository after tableEntityRepository.save so that viewEntityRepository is updated with the latest TableEntity status (assuming the ViewEntity's view is updated upon the save on TableEntity's table)?

Comment: I would imagine that the `commit` is not done until after the `method` successfully returns.  Od course you could `fudge` this as `ret.setStatus(newStatus);`

Comment: Use `saveAndFlush` instead of `save`. Also make sure you are executing all of this inside a transaction and that you haven't yet loaded the `ViewEntity` before (else it might come from the first level cache instead of from the database).

Comment: @jordiburgos That is not a duplicate of this question. The OP needs to see updated data from the database, not restart their spring context.

Comment: I'm using the CrudRepository, which does not have the saveAndFlush function. I've tried moving the save() to it's own method, as well as annotating the method with @transactional, but still no luck.

Comment: Just an update, I'd rather not programmatically restart the context as this is for an endpoint that will be frequently used. 

I've tried changing the repositories to JpaRepository to use the saveAndFlush() and flush() options, I've tried sleep (in case there is some delay in the view being updated after the save on the TableEntity repository).  I've tried the @Transactional annotation on the method and the repositories.  So far, no luck.

Comment: The strange thing is that the same scenario works in the integration spock test (saving to the TableEntity repository and getting the updated ViewEntity from the ViewEntity repository within the same function block), so I thought it may be some caching issue.  However I'm not using any caching for either Hibernate or SpringBoot, and the default Hibernate first level cache should not affect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the EntityManager to refresh the return item (which requires the @Transactional annotation), as well as using saveAndFlush() instead of save(), fixed this issue:

```
class MyService {
  @Autowired
  ViewEntityRepository viewEntityRepository;

  @Autowired
  TableEntityRepository tableEntityRepository;

  @PersistenceContext
  EntityManager entityManager

  @Transactional
  ViewEntity updateTableEntity(String newStatus, TableEntity tableEntity) {
      ViewEntity ret = viewEntityRepository.findBySharedId(tableEntity.SharedId);
      tableEntity.status = newStatus;
      tableEntityRepository.saveAndFlush(viewEntity);
      entityManager.refresh(ret)
      return ret;
  }
}
```